# Selenium exception: element not intractable

Tags: selenium-webdriver, java, selenium-ide

[image]

```
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30); 
    WebElement button = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//div[contains(@class,'RadioButton_radioButton__12O81')]//label[contains(@for,'2')])"))));
    button.click();
```

Radio button selection...

Comment: Could you share the HTML and stacktrace?

Comment: check updated info...

Answer (score 1):

The problem is probably on this `Thread.sleep`. You could add an explicit wait for the element before clicking.

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, timeout); 
WebElement button = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(locator));
button.click();
```

It will check constantly the state of the element and continue to the click as soon as it is clickable (for *timeout* seconds maximum).

Comment: Tried dear no luck...Expected condition failed: waiting for element to be clickable: [[ChromeDriver: chrome on XP (83f26d23ff23e73792538048339074f5)] -> xpath: (//div[contai

Comment: Probably your locator is wrong, to select the radio button, you must click on the input tag, not on the label - a label is never clickable.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, your radio button is clickable at some other point. So you need to clearly identify the clickable element in your DOM.
Try this may it help-

```
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30); 
    WebElement button = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//div[@class='RadioButton_radioButton__12O81']/input"))));
    button.click();
```

Comment: no luck.. thank you for your help dear.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this Radio button falls under the category of Pseudo Element (::before, ::after things)

Can you try clicking using Action Classes here:
Actions action = new Actions();
action.moveToElement(locator).moveByOffset(100, 0).click(),build().perform();

Let me know on this!